# How to multiply value in table column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have to edit table in my database. I have column `[Width]` and I have to multiply this `[Width] * 10` for all rows. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET WIDTH = WIDTH * 10
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by using `UPDATE` query like this:

```
UPDATE Mytable SET [Width] = [Width] * 10
```

Normal syntax is:

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET <column_name> = <value> [WHERE <condition>]
```

But since you want to update all records you don't need to add `WHERE` condition.

For more see [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx) and [UPDATE Basics in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/update--basics-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE mytable SET myfield = myfield * 10
```

Answer (score 3):

```
update table_name set column_name = [width] * 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
update YourTable
   set [Width] = [Width] * 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the column by using the update statement and use the OUTPUT clause to give you and idea of the changes (if you are using 2008 +). Put the whole thing in a transaction and rollback if you have any doubts and commit the changes at your leisure.

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE tablename SET width = width * 10
OUTPUT inserted.width, deleted.width

ROLLBACK TRAN

--COMMIT TRAN